# confusion on delegation by using the new on method

Tags: jquery

I have a li `(<li>)` that contain a checkbox, and the li I used on() with an event, like this:

```
    $('li').on('click', 'li', function(){

});
```

1. what happen if I don't put the 2nd parameter which is li?
2. I click on my checkbox which I also apply to click(), the li's event fire..

how delegation work? I'm confused with the uses of on() since the delegate method had been deprecated..

Comment: Your question is not clear. Having the delegate selector the same as the filter is very odd. Not including the second parameter will use the standard non-delegated event handler on the `li` element.

Comment: I have to prevent the li event from firing because i want to do something with the checkbox, and the checkbox is within the li..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry for the bad grammar above :)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop propagation of the event. See this jFiddle [[example]](http://jsfiddle.net/f2b3V/)

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
   $('p').text('li stuff');
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('p').text('input checkbox stuff');
});
```